# Objective-C Decode Base 64, buffer

Tags: objective-c, base64, decode

I'm trying to decode the string, please see below, from base64.

```
NSString *base64String=@"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";
NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decodedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", decodedString);
```

"Null" appear in the log. I think the problem due to the encoded string, this string is coming from a string encryption (AES128, ECB).

Could you please tell me if I miss something, I didn't see a special parameters about that.

Comment: Did you try logging `decodedData`? Are you absolutely sure it gives a valid UTF-8 string? If it was originally AES128 output it shouldn't be expected to be. What are you trying to achieve with the conversion into `decodedString`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, you are right I'm not sure to take the right way. Just for information, see after the process about the original data : 
JSON => encode64 => crypt AES128 ECB => encode64.

I'm trying to reverse this process step by step due to my lack of knowledge.
See below the log about decodedData:

> <6beccfa1 649f7fea 253e6b5a a64e53d3 70c7d2f3 7fdcfd3c 8bb79e6c c245331e 798465ef 74312123 e6c14d52 afef4b92 c682c74e bb441837 f0953f6a 4a9262c5 6aed77b3 20d99818 cdb383e0 13597ebf c1fdcc09 50addecf 33e49773 729b12fa 69726aec f42fb0cb b4408fbf 95554a75 c5a47473 8bcbdc45 05685af3 c095ed76 75f5ce49 15899c4f 4dc086b5 3785a625 a652939e 76d178cd d76a1f4f 2c282b2a 50341dc0 38bf8900 68d7716a bc12ebc9 583316e0 83776a6c 7d64dd01 8ee1a4c1 cdd4c10d 4791532f 63f6b785 e5d7386e a9e641e1 da3f6c5f 28b11afd ce94dc54 4a749fc0 ccc6dc0c 3920dec6 001f9763 9997a81a 50bae9f0 f9baf9a0 8900be62 8fc4e02d 42215358 c13ce2d2 ce99d76c 48628805 c7285883 84c77dd3 44ca3744 7220a250 0d99bc09 324dd92b 08a4df15 b1b08391 169d0682 09ad39cd 2d53cb02 675b92f2 6387fc8f 6e3434ce ed48a161 4796eaa4 03783a39 73df7662 2cbb0145 a6a683ae 66290601 552d731e 47376fa0 e5bdf951 747e27db bc047b7d 13f303b3 35e05b90 144048be 10cb0f2c 6ffd4715 17dbe33d 1ac298fb a88ab9b4 8584dc11 5c49197f c52c60cc 6f8d6107 b7a65b5b 5d915123 b0a31bca 5046f245 257fa548 12826aa0 47323

May be I can try to uncrypt the decodedData